# Invoke a method continuously in background service without blocking the app xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have defined a background service as follows. I have a `DatabaseClass` in my PCL that contains an `async` method `InsertIntoDb`. I have method `StartDetect` which is a listener that continuously make detection of bluetooth tags and fill up an `ObservableCollection` with the data detected. I want these method to continuously run in background, especially the `InsertIntoDb` that should continuously inserts data into the database while the app is detecting . How can I achieve this in background service in Xamarin.android ? Please help.

```
public class BroadcastService : Service
{
IBinder mBinder;


[return: GeneratedEnum]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{

    Toast.MakeText(this, "BroadcastService is running ", ToastLength.Long).Show();

   DatabaseClass db = new DatabaseClass();

  ObservableCollection<Trucks> allTrucks = new ObservableCollection<Trucks();
      IDetect deObj = new Detect();
      allTrucks =  deObj.StartDetect();
      db.InsertIntoDb(allTrucks);

    base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return StartCommandResult.Sticky;

}
```

Comment: You need to invoke those methods on a background thread (i.e. Task.Run or start a new thread manually) as an Android `Service` runs on the Main/UI thread. Service types like `IntentService` invoke their own worker thread, but depending upon which APIs you are running on, you might want to look at `JobIntentService` to avoid the OS "Doze"'ing your service.

Comment: Review : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

Comment: Yes. I have defined an intent to start this service as the device boots up. My case is I want this background service to separately. As I launch the app manually, it should be a different thread executing the detection and inserting the data.  My question is how can I make these methods run on a separate thread and be continuously running ?

Comment: Place those methods in a new thread (`Task.Run` will work)

Comment: What if I want to call the methods continuously after every 3 mins ?
Note that my method `deObj.StartDetect();` is a `listener`.

Comment: Also, another point I would like to add.. Suppose I start the manually. Now two threads will be invoking the same methods and I may get duplicate data which is fine. But the db connection is single in the `DatabaseClass`. Would this be an issue ?

Comment: `StartCommandResult` of a **`Service`** is called on the main thread, what you  do inside of it is up to you as long as you do not block the return from it (otherwise the OS can/will kill it). So you can start a new thread or use one from the threadpool (`Task.Run`). Yes, you would need to provide locking within your thread(s) as you typically want access serialized to Sqlite (lots of existing SO Questions/answers concerning Android/Multi-threading/SQLite access) and only have **one** SQLite connection that is shared and who's access is serialized.

Comment: Thank you for your enlightenment. Appreciated :)